How to remove the distributional part of a brms model with update()
I'm working with the brms package and fitting models using distributional formulas like this:
library(brms)
fml <- bf(mpg ~ hp, sigma ~ cyl)
mdl <- brm(fml, data = mtcars)

I want to programmatically remove the sigma part from this formula and refit the model using the update() function to avoid a full refit. Using update() is much faster because it avoids recompiling the Stan model.
I tried the following approach, but sigma is still part of the model:
fml_no_sigma <- fml$formula  # extracting main formula
mdl_no_sigma <- update(mdl, formula = fml_no_sigma)

However, the sigma part remains in the updated model.
Refitting the model with fml$formula does remove the sigma but is much slower than using updated:
brm(fml$formula, data = mtcars)

Is there a way to use update() to remove the sigma part without refitting the entire model from scratch?

Maybe fml$pforms <- list() ?

I don't think this is possible. You need to change the Stan code and that requires recompilation. I believe update without recompilation only works with new data.

@@G.Grothendieck This doesn't work neither.
@Roland can you post a response saying that it's not possible so I can approve it? Thanks

I'm only 90 % confident. For an authoritive answer more knowledge regarding brms internals would be needed.

Yes I agree with @Roland. Documentation for update() https://paulbuerkner.com/brms/reference/update.brmsfit.html says that by default "update tries to figure out internally, if recompilation is necessary." Thus there may be changes to the model formula passed to update that would require changes to the Stan code. That would mean the model has to be recompiled.

And I tried mdl2 <- update(mdl, formula = bf(mpg ~ hp, sigma ~ 1)) to see if that would work without recompilation, but that results in Replacing initial definitions of parameters 'sigma'. The desired updates require recompiling the model
